# Rails on IronRuby (IIS 6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iis-6, ironruby

I'm trying to get Rails running on a IIS 6 webserver using IronRuby, but without success. I have followed [this webcast](http://www.iamnotmyself.com/CategoryView,category,IronRuby.aspx) and got it running on IIS 7, but can't make it work on a IIS 6 server. I need some help to get this to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you describe the problem/error/...?

Answer (score 1):

you have to set a wild card mapping to aspnet_isapi.dll
The problem is probably that it doesn't pass extensionless urls to the .net pipeline.
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5c5ae5e0-f4f9-44b0-a743-f4c3a5ff68ec.mspx?mfr=true

If this isn't the problem please provide more information as to errors etc.

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts..

1. Casual Jim is partially right, you need to do a wild card mapping to get all requests to go through the ASAPI filter for .NET. When I got this working on IIS 5.1 where there is no wild card mapping, I created an extension map for *.rails and then had to change my routing to add that to the end of all requests.
2. If you used the [web.config](http://gist.github.com/376705) that I posted in my video, it will only work in IIS7. Versions 6 and lower define handlers in a different place.

IIS7: configuration>system.webServer>handlers>add

IIS6: configuration>system.web>httpHandlers>add